# CSS: Trying to move buttons to the right side. Only works with "Position: absolute", but it breaks my horizontal list

Tags: css, position

CSS:

```
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
#btn{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #22;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
    #btn:hover{
      background: #333;
      color: #fff;
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      }
    #btn.fb:hover{
      background: #3b5998;
      }
    #btn.tw:hover{
      background: #55ACEE;
      }
    #btn.yt:hover{
      background: #b31217;
      }
```

HTML

```
<ul>
      <li>
        <button class='fb' id='btn'>Facebook</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class='tw' id='btn'>Twitter</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class='yt' id='btn'>Youtube</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

It's only going to the right side when put the "Position: Absolute" in there, I tried going to check w3schools, but they say the same thing (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). I honestly have no idea what's wrong, hopefully you guys can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be `float:right` in the css for `#btn`

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#btn{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    background: #22;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#btn:hover{
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#btn.fb:hover{
    background: #3b5998;
}
#btn.tw:hover{
    background: #55ACEE;
}
#btn.yt:hover{
    background: #b31217;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <button class='yt' id='btn'>Youtube</button>
    </li>    
    <li>
        <button class='tw' id='btn'>Twitter</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class='fb' id='btn'>Facebook</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, I'm so dumb, sorry sir.

Answer (score 0):

Float the list items right.

```
li {
    float: right;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't reuse an ID (#btn) on multiple elements, use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Then it will work. Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08m7966g/1/)